# UITableViewCell is not receiving the cell object at specified index path

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview

I am manually creating a tableViewCell (which is custom) by specifying an indexPath. For some reason, sometimes the cell will receive the cell object and sometimes it will not contain an object. I know a cell exists at the indexPath specified, but more some reason the code sometimes can't get the object from it. Any ideas?

```
-(BOOL)checkRequiredValues {

    NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath;
    CheckoutCell *cell;

    cellIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
    cell = (CheckoutCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:cellIndexPath];

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` on `UITableView` returns `nil` if the cell is not visible:

> An object representing a cell of the table or `nil` if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range.

If you would like to get a cell all the time, call the same method on your data source:

```
cell = (CheckoutCell *)[self.tableView.dataSource
    tableView:self.tableView
    cellForRowAtIndexPath:cellIndexPath
];
```